# Powershell error trying to save thumbnail to AzureAD

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

So I'm trying to create a powershell script to sync our Active Directory user photos to AzureAD (and eventually Office365, but one task at a time, right?).  We have valid photos stored in AD.  The eventual goal is to have this script run on a regular basis.  Anyway...

```
import-module activedirectory
import-module AzureAD

$list = GET-ADuser <actual username here> -properties thumbnailphoto

function SaveToAzureAD()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String] $AccountName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][Array] $Thumbnail
        
    )

    Connect-AzureAD 

    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "email address: "
    write-output "$AccountName@<insert domain here>"
    
    
    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "AD User account info: "
    $AdUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$AccountName@<insert domain here>'"

   

    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "Set thumbnail: "

    Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId $ADUser.ObjectID -ImageByteArray $Thumbnail
    
    return "done"
}


Foreach ($User in $list)
{
    
    If ($User.thumbnailphoto)
    {
        Write-Output $user.thumbnailphoto.GetType()
        
        SaveToAzureAD($User.SamAccountName) -Thumbnail $User.Thumbnailphoto
        Write-Output "done loop"
    }
 }
```

Everything works as you expect.  I get the pop up to log into with our Office365 stuff.  I'm able to pull the correct objectID and get the byte array representing the thumbnail image that I'm after (I've written the file out to disk - it's the correct one).  Then when it comes to calling Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto, I pass the objectID and the byte array (in `$Thumbnail`) but it gives me an error and I've been beating my head against it.

I want to take the byte array and pass it to the Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto call.  As near as I can tell, it's correct.  Here is the error...

```
Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto :  
At <path to script>\getphotos.ps1:87 char:9
+         Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId $ADUser.ObjectID -Ima ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.PowerShell.Custom.Cmdlet.SetAzureADUserThumbnailPhotoCustom
```

I have done a bunch of googling trying to figure this out.

- There were several suggestions from Stack Overflow that suggested
  that the problem was the execution policy.  I don't think that's the
  case.  I have powershell set to remotesigned.
- There was a suggestion about the module not having the correct permissions/rights.  Near as I can tell, AzureAD and ActiveDirectory have what they need.
- I've tried updating the modules.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what to try next?

Also, I know I can just save the file and then read it in again and send it that way but I'd like to avoid doing that if I can.

Also, the documentation for Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto REALLY needs more examples of all of the functionality...

Comment: Did you happen to check the output of the `$ADUser.ObjectID` - is the output coming as expected ?  - meaning are you getting the user's object id ?

Comment: Hi @SatyaV, yes, I did.  And yes, it does.  Everything works great if I write the file to the file system.  The problem is if I try to keep it all in memory it fails and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer :**

Looks like a issue with the code in the module.

Looks like you will not be able to update using the ImageByteArray.

Less likely can be fixed at your end.

**Long Answer :**

I tried decompiling the module as per the error `Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.PowerShell.Custom.Cmdlet.SetAzureADUserThumbnailPhotoCustom`

This uses an internal method, ImageUtils.GetImage

[image]

I was tracking this function and saw the definition - so at the top there is a condition check :

```
 public static Image GetImage(Stream fileStream, string filePath, byte[] imageByteArray)
        {
            Image image;
            if (fileStream == null && filePath == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(" ");
            }
.
. 
.
.
<Excluding the rest code for brevitity>
```

This condition checks only for filestream and filepath (not for ImageByteArray - which is should not be the case. Ideally, in my opinion - there should be check for nullness of ImageByteArray )

So when you execute :

```
Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId $ADUser.ObjectID -ImageByteArray $Thumbnail
```

by default parameters `FileStream` and `FilePath` are set to null.

On the first check, since both are null - it throws the argument exception as per the the code.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  Thank you for that.  I guess I should see about approaching the author for a resolution then.  

Comment: Yes agreed writing the byte[] array to a memory stream and using the FileStream parameter looks like the best workaround. I put the code I'm using here.

https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2021/02/the-set-azureaduserthumbnailphoto.html